# jQuery clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following hover function

```
function tt_attachToBase(){
        jQuery.each(bases,
            function(index,base){

                jQuery(base).hover(function() {  
                         jQuery(base).showTipTimer = setInterval( function(){tt_locateBase(base);} , 3000 ); 
                             },  
                            function() {  
                                clearInterval(jQuery(base).showTipTimer);
                                tt_hideTip();
                                    }

                    }); 
            }

        );
```

inside tt_locateBase() I also clear interval like this

```
tt_locateBase(base){
clearInterval(jQuery(base).showTipTimer);
//code to sidplay tooltip
}
```

the tooltip does display after an interval, but the interval it seems is never cleared since the tooltip keep recurring over base. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What valu has jQuery(base).showTipTimer inside tt_locateBase?

Comment: sorry I pass it base from hover function, I edited the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a property to the return value of `jQuery(base)` will only affect that specific object. If you fetch `jQuery(base)` a second time it won't be carrying that property.

What you're currently doing is equivalent to the code below:

```
function return_something() {
    return ['foo', 'bar'];
}

var first_fetch = return_something();
// => ['foo', 'bar']
first_fetch.push('baz'); // => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

var second_fetch = return_something(); // => ['foo, 'bar']
```

#### Solution

Attach it as [a data field](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead, perhaps? This way, it will affect the actual object in the DOM, and the jQuery object will carry that data value in subsequent fetches.

```
jQuery(base).data('showTipTimer', 
  setInterval(function(){tt_locateBase(base);} , 3000));
```

Then clear with:

```
clearInterval(jQuery(base).data('showTipTimer'));
```

Comment: firebug gives me a "missing ) after arguments" error on jQuery(base).data('showTipTimer', setInterval(function(){tt_locateBase(base);} , 3000);    adding an extra pair of () around setinterval and 3000 also doesnt solve the problem..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a parenthesis at the end. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
   jQuery(base).hover(function() {  
         var idInterval = setInterval( function(){tt_locateBase(base, idInterval);} , 3000 ); 
                         },
```

and then

```
tt_locateBase(base, i){
clearInterval(i);
//code to sidplay tooltip
}
```

Comment: this will probably work but there are multiple tooltips os the page so I would rather attach an individual timer to each base